# How loud really are ultrasound transducers?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, power, resonance

There are a plethora of mini ultrasound transducers available. Many of which have a Sound Level SPL > 110dB. This seems extremely "loud". If you were to listen to one of these transducers, would they have the same effect (disregarding frequency) on your ears as a 110dB chainsaw? Listening to a chainsaw is not a pleasant experience, but I am dubious that such a small transducer could also generate as unpleasant a sound... What other factors are at play?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, because you can't disregard frequency.  The echolocation sounds used by bats, for instance, can be *extremely* loud: they can have SPLs of something like $140\,\mathrm{dB}$ (see [here](https://doi.org/10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0002036)).  Yet bats do not deafen us.

The reason they don't deafen us is because the sound they produce is very far outside the frequency range to which our ears are sensitive.

A more interesting question is why bats don't deafen *bats*.  I think they have special arrangements whereby, when they are emitting pulses, their ears are somehow shut down to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.cdc.gov/nceh/hearing_loss/how_does_loud_noise_cause_hearing_loss.html

The hairs in your inner ear that respond to sound can be damaged by loud sounds. But each hair responds to one frequency. That frequency vibrates the hair. Loud sounds vibrate them too hard. But no hairs respond to ultrasound.

This is different from light. UV light is highly energetic. It can damage skin and other cells (eye cells) even though you can't see it.